# Resize the MFMailComposeViewController and prevent it from covering the whole screen

Tags: ios, iphone, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I have a MFMailComposeViewController, and it's called using this method:

```
    - (IBAction)sendEmail:(id)sender {

    NSArray *toRecipents = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"email@email.com"];

    MFMailComposeViewController *mc = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    mc.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [mc setSubject:@"Email"];
    [mc setMessageBody:message.text isHTML:NO];
    [mc setToRecipients:toRecipents];

    // Present mail view controller on screen
    [self presentViewController:mc animated:YES completion:NULL];

}
```

I want when the controller loads up , I want his height to be 50 pixels less than the view's height, I don't want him to take the whole screen. Is there any way to do so?.

EDIT: The problem I'm facing is, this MFMailComposeViewController I'm calling , is initially inside a view controller that was called using a modal page curl effect, so the curl effect is preventing me to push the send email button! this is a pic

[image]

So no matter how much u try, u just can't click the send button…what can i do in this situation without getting rejected by apple

EDIT 2:
Can i just close the modal curl page effect and then pop up this view controller?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there if no standard or allowed way to do what you want. 
Also I would be concerned about passing approval since Apple indicates the following regarding mail composer:

*Important: The view hierarchy of this class is private and you must not modify it. You can, however, customize the appearance of an instance by using the UIAppearance protocol.
After presenting a mail comopose view controller, your app cannot change the email content. The user can edit the content of a presented instance but the system ignores programmatic changes. If you want to set values for the content fields, do so before presenting the interface.* [class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html)

If you've some custom design requirements for sending emails I'd recommend implementing your own views and using some server to send email, but I'm not sure how hard are your design requirements.

Comment: From the Docs, UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl is defined to cover part of your presented viewController (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) So I'm not very sure why you would like to use that kind of modal presentation style, since it's going to cover also the CANCEL button of your email composer...

Answer (score 0):

Try to change frame of `MFMailComposeViewController` manually and use `addSubview:` instead of `presentViewController:animated:completion:`:

```
mc.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 400);
// Use addSubview: insead of [self presentViewController:mc animated:YES completion:NULL];
[self.view addSubview:mc.view];
```

[image]

**Notice:** I am not sure this this behaviour would be passed through Apple App Store approval process.